# Ubuntu initial configuration script errors

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm newbie to linux and I'm trying to make an initial configuration script for basic users passwords, SSH rules and system config of Hostname & timezone as below,

```
 1  #!/bin/bash
 2  # Login as Root
 3  sudo su -
 4  # Set Root password
 5  echo -e "dumppassword\ndumppassword" | passwd root
 6  # Set default user ubuntu password
 7  echo -e "dumppasswords\ndumppassword" | passwd ubuntu
 8  # SSH configuration
 9  # Permit SSH password Authentication
10  # Make a copy of sshd_config file with suffix in _backup_YYYY-MM-DD format
11  # Comment out PasswordAuthentication no
12  sudo sed -i_backup_`date +%F` -e '/^PasswordAuthentication no/ s/^#*/#/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
13  # Add PasswordAuthentication yes after the commented line #PasswordAuthentication no
14  sudo sed -i '/^#PasswordAuthentication no/a PasswordAuthentication yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
15  # Permit SSH Root login
16  # Comment out PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
17  sudo sed -i -e '/^PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/ s/^#*/#/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
18  # Add PermitRootLogin yes after the commented line #PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
19  sudo sed -i '/^#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/a PermitRootLogin yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
20  # Restart SSh service
21  sudo service ssh restart
22  # Set timezone
23  sudo timedatectl set-timezone Africa/Cairo
24  # Set Hostname
25  # Set the current hostname variable
26  CUR_HOSTNAME=$(cat /etc/hostname)
27  # Set the desired new hostname
28  NEW_HOSTNAME="DufDuf"
29  # Make changes
30  sudo sed -i 's/^"$CUR_HOSTNAME"/"$NEW_HOSTNAME"/' /etc/hostname
31  sudo sed -i 's/^"$CUR_HOSTNAME"/"$NEW_HOSTNAME"/' /etc/hosts
32  # Update Repositories
33  sudo apt-get update
34  sudo apt update
```

But I'm getting below errors, I couldn't figure it out.

```
'u: invalid option -- '
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -m, -p,
  --preserve-environment        do not reset environment variables, and
                                keep the same shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd

' does not existot
' does not existuntu
: No such file or directoryhd_config
: No such file or directoryhd_config
: No such file or directoryhd_config
: No such file or directoryhd_config
 * Usage: /etc/init.d/ssh {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|try-restart|status}
Failed to set time zone: Invalid time zone 'Africa/Cairo
'
: No such file or directoryme
: No such file or directory
E: Invalid operation update
E: Invalid operation update
```

Anyone could help me plz

Thanks,

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging? Such as removing all the code and then add one line at a time back to see where the first error occurs. Or add some `echo` debug statements. Lots of basic steps you can take to at least narrow down the problem first.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. `1  #!/bin/bash
     2  # Login as Root
     3  sudo su -
     4  whoami `

Comment: This gives me this error`'u: invalid option -- '
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -m, -p,
  --preserve-environment        do not reset environment variables, and
                                keep the same shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd

Script.sh: line 4: $'whoami\r': command not found`. It couldn't recognize `sudo su -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this out after long search. The problem is, executing the script with root won't work with

```
sudo su -
```

Instead, below code force script to run in a privileged mode

```
# Force script to run as Root
if [ $EUID != 0 ];
then
    sudo bash "$0" "$@";
    exit "$?";
fi

# For test, run whoami, expected result is root.
echo `whoami`
```